# Casting JSON to complex types

Tags: json, angular, typescript, casting, jsonserializer

I am trying to cast my `http.get` response to actual object -> in my specific case array of complex objects.

In a normal scenario, where you don't need any specific casting, you could do the following (simplified):

```
return this.httpClient.get(api, this._options_get)
  .pipe(
    map((response: any) => {
      return response.value as NewProduct[];
    })
  );
```

As my need is to actually cast this to an object, I have created this static method which does that:

```
static toProduct(otherProduct: any): NewProduct {
    let item = new NewProduct();

    Object.keys(otherProduct).forEach(prop => {
        if (typeof otherProduct[prop] === "object" && otherProduct[prop]) {
            if (!item.hasOwnProperty(prop))
                item[prop] = otherProduct[prop];
            Object.assign(item[prop], otherProduct[prop]);
        }
        else
            item[prop] = otherProduct[prop];
    })

    return item;
}
```

Under `Object.assign` I am taking already existing object which was initialized under first line and I am simply copying all the properties from the `otherProduct` to it. However I start to face problem when it comes to array of objects. Example (with simplified class):

```
export class Person {
    name:string;
    age:number;
    addresses:Address[] = [];
}
export class Address {
    street:string;
    city:string;
    fullAddress() : string { return this.street + this.city; }
}
```

As soon as I have this sort of array, I don't have any initial object in `item`. This means that there is no initial constructor of a class which results in simple `Object`. This is no error for JavaScript or TypeScript; however when I am trying to access internal method of a class (in our simplified case `fullAddress()`, I won't be able to.

The reason why I need that is that I am overriding `toString()` method on my sub-classes, which is necessary for `MatTableDataSource` when you use the `filter` method (which works with strings).

Is there a way how to retrieve elements from `http.get()` and properly map results to typed objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're being too generic. You're creating objects of objects, not objects of Product with children of Addresses.

If you want to create a new product you're going to have to understand the relationship between the api's results and the data you want in the UI.

Because you're using classes and not interfaces and want to inherit the functions, the only way to get new Addresses into the new object is with the `new` keyword.

And you'll have to loop through.  You're not going to find a shortcut for this.  You're going to need to loop through the data and transform it.  If your api is giving you an ApiPerson then you'll want to do something like this:

```
const addresses = apiPerson.addresses.map((apiAddress) => {
    const address = new Address();
    // map properties of apiAddress to address...
    return address;
});
```

Now that you have the `addresses`, you can map the `apiPerson` to a `new Person()`'s properties and then set the `newPerson.addresses = address`.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a better way how to manage this. Thank you for your answer